# How to implement a specific head or top like this in conTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, context-mkii

all
  I want to use conTeXt for writing my resume, I found the head like the red area very awesome, but I don't know how to implement it, or what elements I should use to do it? After reading something, I only think I should have a specific head, I am right?

[image]

​please any one help me, Thanks in advance!

UPDATED:
I found [context refer manual 11.3 Variations in titles](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) , there is a snippet, which seemly helps me, the following code:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\setuppagenumbering[location=footer, right]
\unexpanded\def\HeadTitle#1#2%
{\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
\hfill
\setupframed[height=5cm,offset=.5em,frame=off,backgroundcolor=red]
\framed[width=8cm,align=left]{#1}%
\framed[width=12cm,align=right,leftframe=off]{#2}%
\egroup}
\setuplayout
[topspace=\zeropoint,
 height=fit,
 footerdistance=2cm]
 \showframe
 \useURL[aurl][http://cs.ucsd.edu/~mmoghimi][][
 http://cs.ucsd.edu/~mmoghimi]
 \starttext
 \HeadTitle{{\tfb Mohammad Moghimi}

Curriculum Vitae}{9234 Regents Rd Apt H

La Jolla, CA, 92037

(858) 888-3337

mmoghimi@cs.cornell.edu

\url[aurl]}
\stoptext
```

It will generate almost satisfied result:

[image]

Only question is that what should I do for adding a wider blank between the left and right side?

Comment: It looks like [`moderncv`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) class to me, but I don't think that class has ConTeXt support. (But I very well may be wrong about ConTeXt support.)

Comment: @PaulGessler, it is for Latex, but thank you!

Comment: @PaulGessler, I updated my question , can you help me now? Thanks!

Comment: Where it says `align=left` and `align=right`, you probably want them the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *Caveat emptor ...*

You should know that I do not recall ever running `context` before and, judging by the first run, `context` doesn't recall my ever running it either. (Why is it trying to glob what it thinks are weird filenames like `ChangeLog`?)

---

Anyway, I got this

[image: output]

from this

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\setuppagenumbering[location=footer, right]
\unexpanded\def\HeadTitle#1#2%
{\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
\hfill
\setupframed[height=5cm,offset=.5em,frame=off,backgroundcolor=red]
\framed[width=.5\textwidth,align=right]{#1}%
\framed[width=.5\textwidth,align=left,leftframe=off]{#2}%
\egroup}
\setuplayout
[topspace=\zeropoint,
 height=fit,
 footerdistance=2cm]
 \showframe
 \useURL[aurl][http://cs.ucsd.edu/~mmoghimi][][
 http://cs.ucsd.edu/~mmoghimi]
 \starttext
 \HeadTitle{{\tfb Mohammad Moghimi}

Curriculum Vitae}{9234 Regents Rd Apt H

La Jolla, CA, 92037

(858) 888-3337

mmoghimi@cs.cornell.edu

\url[aurl]}
\stoptext
```

which is surely bad in all kinds of ways I don't know about!

Comment: Yippee! Images came back again! I can even see my own!!

Comment: You are great! Thank you very much! Your answer make me step further in conTeXt!

Comment: Only question, What's meaning of ".5\textwidth"? Thanks!

Comment: @abelard2008 the `\textwidth` is equal to the width of the text block (the paper width less the left and right margins, offset etc.) .`.5` just says to use half of that for each frame.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a table, for example, [tabulate](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Tabulate)

```
\showframe % For visual debugging

\useURL[aurl][http://cs.ucsd.edu/~mmoghimi][][http://cs.ucsd.edu/~mmoghimi]
\starttext
\starttabulate[|lp(0.5\textwidth)|rp(0.45\textwidth)S|]
  \NC {\tfb Mohammad Moghimi}\crlf 
      \italic{Curriculum Vitae}
  \NC 9234 Regents Rd Apt H \crlf
      La Jolla, CA, 92037 \crlf
      (858) 888-3337 \crlf
      mmoghimi@cs.cornell.edu \crlf
      \url[aurl]
  \NC \NR
\stoptabulate
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]